# Recovering HyperSQL Database

Tags: java, jboss, recovery, hsqldb, data-recovery

We are using JBoss 4.0.3 SP1 using Hypersonic as its internal storage engine (timers, queues, etc.)

The database is no longer accessible (most likely data corruption) giving error; **Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: old version database must be shutdown**.

Is there a way or command to shutdown the database to recover the data (~150MB) stuck in the flat file?

Edit

Resolved the connection problem by downgrading to Hypersonic 1.8. How ever the database itself is corrupt. You have rows with duplicate keys, and lots of null fields. Having read [this article](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/ConfigJBossMQDB) and [this one](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/HypersonicProduction), i'm in the process of changing the default JBossMQ database to MS SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the hsql documentation the command is [SHUTDOWN](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#shutdown-section). As far as I remember, hsql saves the data as a set of sql queries, so you need to have a look on the file.

Notice that [according to JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/HypersonicProduction),

> Hypersonic(HSQLDB) SHOULD NOT be used
>   in production at all.  It is not
>   suitable for production use.

Comment: i noted that as well, guess this is the time you curse your predecessors.